# AWS ALB SSL/TLS offloading security

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-alb

AWS ALBs allow one to configure an SSL/TLS certificate for encrypting traffic between the client and the LB. Traffic between the LB and the target can be protected with a certificate, but target certificates are not validated... as outlined here: https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-compliance-hipaa/issues/9#issuecomment-693746199

Question: Does traffic within a VPC require additional measures to secure and prevent unauthorized access? Does AWS VPC have additional security mechanisms to prevent snooping, or unauthorized access to unencrypted traffic flowing within a VPC? Are their any tangible benefits to applying a certificate to the LB target in the above scenario considering that the certificate will not be validated?

Answer (score 0):

AWS VPC networking is usually considered sufficiently secured and private that you don't need to encrypt traffic inside your VPC. However, for compliance reasons a lot of traffic inside a VPC is encrypted with TLS.

AWS VPC doesn't let you see traffic that isn't meant for that resource.

Read up on the [AWS Hyperplane](https://youtu.be/8gc2DgBqo9U?t=2098) to understand more about security and how this works.